# 'When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key' when adding to list of navigation properties EF Core

Tags: c#, mysql, database, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am using EF Core 3.1.23 w .NET Core 3.1

**Explanation:**

I am storing information about an xml file in a database.

The Xml File is stored in the following format:

```
<section name="NAME">
        <key name="NAME" value="0" />
        ...
</section>
```

The xml file has around 40 sections, each with 1 - 20 fields (keys)

- Each section has many keys
- Each key has 1 section

**Corresponding Database classes:**

```
    public class XmlKey
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual XmlSection XmlSection { get; set; }
        public int? XmlSectionId { get; set; }
    }

    public class XmlSection
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public List<XmlKey> Keys { get; set; }
    }

    public class XmlMapping
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public virtual XmlKey XmlKey { get; set; }
        public int? XmlKeyId { get; set; }

        public int Value { get; set; }
    }
```

- Each Mapping is a key and a value
- Each configuration has many mappings

**Executed code:**

```
    using (DatabaseContext dbContext = new DatabaseContext())
            {
                //add new mappings that are not in the database
                dbContext.AddRange(XmlMappings);


                //create new configuration and add to list of nav props
                var config = new XmlConfiguration()
                {
                    Name = Name,
                    Mappings = XmlMappings.ToList()
                };

                //Attach vs Add? Have tried both here in every location with same result
                dbContext.XmlConfigurations.Attach(config);
                dbContext.SaveChanges();
            }
```

When attemping to create a new configuration, and adding new mappings to that configuration, if 2 mapped keys have the same section *the following error* is produced:

*'The instance of entity type 'XmlSection' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value '{Id: 12}' is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.'*

The (theoretical) flow of this would go:

1. Create new xml mappings in UI by selecting a Key and a Value (all keys have same section)
2. Create new configuration containing a list of mappings
3. Save mappings now that we know we are for sure saving this configuration
4. Save configuration, add mappings to configuration

However this results in the error above.

**How to avoid this behavior?** I have tried attaching, detaching, loading the navigation props AsNoTracking();, adding nav props instead of setting list explicitly, changed db context options.

Comment: Each `XmlMapping` has a `XmlKey`, each `XmlKey` has a `XmlSection`. But what is `XmlMappings`? Where did it come from? Have you ensured that every `XmlKey` & `XmlSection` with the same id is the same instance? @dante-falzone the most important information in the question is missing.

Comment: For better analysis please show the creation of your `XmlMapping`s.

Answer (score 0):

You created a new `DatabaseContext`.If you have tracked elements in `XmlMapping`s you have to use same `DatabaseContext` you loaded the `XmlMapping` instance from to save them.

Comment: Now that you have the commenting privilege you can clean this up and move the non-answering parts, which are asking clarification questions, into a comment on the question.